# How to insert all textview and edittext fields into same columns in database mysql in Android Studio

Tags: php, android, mysql

Allright let me explain it better.
I want to make an app which has certain set of questions and answers as textview and edittext and in backend i have two columns named as question and answers. I want to insert all textview(question) in question columns and all edittext(answers) in answers columns. Im able to insert one row at a time but not all at one time on button click.

```
public void SendDataToServer(final String name, final String email, final String website){
    class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String QuickName = name ;
            String QuickEmail = email ;
            String QuickWebsite = website;

            //String[] str = {QuickName,QuickEmail,QuickWebsite};

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", QuickName));
            //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", email));

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", QuickEmail));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("website", QuickWebsite));

            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(DataParseUrl);

                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
            return "Data Submit Successfully";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Submit Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
    SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
    sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(name, email, website);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do it.

You want to send all question and answer in one request. And for this you can create a [**JsonRequest** using **Volley**](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/)

And If you want to send using **HttpClient** then you can send your
request as JsonString like this:

```
JSONObject rootObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray dataArr = new JSONArray();
for (int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) // loop will execute total no. of questions
    {
        JSONObject itemObj = new JSONObject();
        itemObj.put("question", "What is your name?");
        itemObj.put("answer", "XYZ");

        dataArr.put(itemObj);
    }
    rootObject.put("data", dataArr);

    // Finally send your all data here
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("request", rootObject.toString()));
```

and on the server side you will get your data from **request** param and then parse the json.

That's it.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: thanku for your quick reply brother.. but this is what i didnt understand itemObj.put("question", "What is your name?"); why we have the value of question and answer as "what is your name?" and "xyz" ? in quotes..what does it mean?

Comment: That is the value you will inserting in the JsonObject that to be sent. you can not send TextView in request, you can get text from TextView and insert in the JsonObject.

Answer (score 1):

use firebase instead of mysql. In firebase all edittext and textview stored in column format.